# foreach loop get the value of an element

Tags: php

I have been stuggling with this for the past couple hours, been trying so hard to get the value of userid and jobprocstatus out of this array.

this is the result of *print_r($result);*

```
 stdClass Object ( [accountid] => 6f3f55f6-67a1-11e4-a7c1-7e542e26bbf0 [userid] => 6f3f650b-67a1-11e4-a7c1-7e542e26bbf0 [cmd] => org.apache.cloudstack.api.command.admin.vm.DeployVMCmdByAdmin [jobstatus] => 1 [jobprocstatus] => 0 [jobresultcode] => 0 [jobresulttype] => object [jobresult] => stdClass Object ( [virtualmachine] => stdClass Object ( [id] => ccfbb592-ebfa-4f18-b861-4ae5e1a15426 [name] => VM-ccfbb592-ebfa-4f18-b861-4ae5e1a15426 [displayname] => VM-ccfbb592-ebfa-4f18-b861-4ae5e1a15426 [account] => admin [domainid] => ea3b19e6-67a0-11e4-a7c1-7e542e26bbf0 [domain] => ROOT [created] => 2014-11-11T17:39:31-0500 [state] => Running [haenable] => [zoneid] => 481b2bdf-90ba-4841-bd5a-f4fbf6027401 [zonename] => Toronto [hostid] => cc66aa5e-6be3-4f35-b538-87a9b09a6fc5 [hostname] => TOR-XENSRV61 [templateid] => ea41cab5-67a0-11e4-a7c1-7e542e26bbf0 [templatename] => CentOS 5.6(64-bit) no GUI (XenServer) [templatedisplaytext] => CentOS 5.6(64-bit) no GUI (XenServer) [passwordenabled] => [serviceofferingid] => 61ee4943-1af5-4168-9dee-fdd128fd58db [serviceofferingname] => Small Instance [cpunumber] => 1 [cpuspeed] => 500 [memory] => 512 [guestosid] => ea9ebb7a-67a0-11e4-a7c1-7e542e26bbf0 [rootdeviceid] => 0 [rootdevicetype] => ROOT [securitygroup] => Array ( ) [nic] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1145aa85-cf95-4215-b1a7-439166698c23 [networkid] => fdeaaf3a-2ee1-45e3-bc15-b325b2ea517c [networkname] => test [netmask] => 255.255.255.0 [gateway] => 192.168.168.1 [ipaddress] => 192.168.168.177 [isolationuri] => vlan://286 [broadcasturi] => vlan://286 [traffictype] => Guest [type] => Isolated [isdefault] => 1 [macaddress] => 02:00:6d:ba:00:16 ) ) [hypervisor] => XenServer [instancename] => i-2-29-VM [tags] => Array ( ) [affinitygroup] => Array ( ) [displayvm] => 1 [isdynamicallyscalable] => 1 [ostypeid] => 142 [jobid] => 3a3c2e81-296b-4f00-906d-d4aac918487c [jobstatus] => 0 ) ) [created] => 2014-11-11T17:39:32-0500 [jobid] => 3a3c2e81-296b-4f00-906d-d4aac918487c )
```

this is what I have tried

```
<?php 

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key : $value <br>";

}
```

output

```
accountid : 6f3f55f6-67a1-11e4-a7c1-7e542e26bbf0 
userid : 6f3f650b-67a1-11e4-a7c1-7e542e26bbf0 
cmd : org.apache.cloudstack.api.command.admin.vm.DeployVMCmdByAdmin 
jobstatus : 1 
jobprocstatus : 0 
jobresultcode : 0 
jobresulttype : object
```

I'm simply trying to get the value of userid element out of this array, however everytime I try

```
echo "$result['userid']";
```

I get a bank screen,and I'm unable to identify the issue.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just for curiosities sake how is `$result` being instantiated? Is it the return of a web service call?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling a restful api

Comment: Interesting, and in the example output is the result of the echo statement in the foreach loop?

Comment: the very first example, is the output of "print_r($result);", the second output is the result of foreach loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the trick for a list of objects

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->userid;
}
```

For a single object:

```
echo $value->userid;
```

`$value` is an object, to get the property of an object you have to use the `->` operator.

If you want to get all the public properties of a list of objects:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $obj) {
    foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $name => $value) {
        echo "Object mapped to $key has property $name => $value";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! got it fixed with your assistance

Answer (score 2):

With this you can access your userid:

```
echo $result->userid;
```

Comment: Thanks Rizer123 for your help :)